# How's the latency with Mac VNC on Windows PC using a crossover cable?

Tags: windows, macos, mac, vnc, vncserver

I use a Windows 8 PC as my main system, and do some programming with Xcode which I use a virtual machine for. However, it doesn't run as smoothly as I would like, so I'm thinking about purchasing a Mac Mini.

My question is if I connect my PC to the Mac Mini directly (via crossover cable, firewire, or usb), would I be able to control the Mac using VNC with almost no latency?

If not, is there any other way I'd be able to use both my PC and the Mac Mini simultaneously (using the same peripherals)?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think you can do a direct connect with any of the cables you have specified. However, you should be able to connect fine over TCP/IP. Just make sure they are both on the same subnet and connect using the IP address.